# Product Information in Prestashop

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

Does anyone know how to get the product information by product ID and show the correct price in prestashop? I have tried a custom SQL query and I can get the product information, however I can't seem to show the correct price since Prestashop stores different price scenarios in separate tables.
ex. ps_product, ps_specific_price, ps_attribute_impact

Comment: Hello, is your prestashop a 1.4 or 1.5 version ?

Comment: @RaphaëlMalié It is 1.5. What the user recommended below did work for a single product, however how would I pull this off for multiple products? This is what I have tried. I get the product IDs that I am using for this module from a custom table I created. I then tried a foreach statement to trigger the new product $displayProducts = ''; foreach($productIDS as $productID) { $displayProducts .= new Product($productID['id_product'], false, $lang_id); }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use the prestashop class.

```
$product = new Product($id_product,false,$lang_id);
```

now you will have all details in $product variable. if you want to take any variable you take like this.

```
$name = $product->name;
```

it is for prestashop 1.5x

Comment: That did work for a single product, however how would I pull this off for multiple products? This is what I have tried. I get the product IDs that I am using for this module from a custom table I created. I then tried a foreach statement to trigger the new product               $displayProducts = ''; foreach($productIDS as $productID) { $displayProducts .= new Product($productID['id_product'], false, $lang_id); }

Comment: for the multiple products you can just use Product::getProducts($id_lang, $start, $limit, $order_by, $order_way) but you can not apply any conditions.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the looping problem. I had to create an array to store all the information in. It ended up working like this

```
$products = array();
foreach($productIDs as $productID) {
$products[$productID['id_product']] = new Product($productID['id_product'], false, '1');
}
```