# How can i print(get) all the product details in my own prestashop module page

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

In prestashop product_list.tpl file, i can print all the product details by using **{print_r($products)}**.

How can i get all the product details like product_list.tpl page in my custom prestashop module

**Even i have tried below codes,**

**$products = new Product($row['id_product'], false, Context::getContext()->language->id);**

but it will give only particular data,can't get(print) full data like product_list.tpl page.

I hope you understand my question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clean your question, it is really hard to read that

Comment: Hi Omis thankyou for your response,

Comment: How can i get the all the product details in my own prestashop module. if i want print $products in prestashop product_list.tpl it will give all the product information.I want that same information in my module

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20004378/product-information-in-prestashop